# Why wxPython carshes while using ID_OPEN, wx.OPEN?

Tags: wxpython

A program for text editor I am developing is bellow. While using the `ID_OPEN`, wxPython terminates. While using `wx.OPEN`, this time also wxPython terminates.

```
import wx
import os
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    # init the frame 
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, size=(200,100))
        self.control =  wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        # creates menu 


        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About" , "Information About This Program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit","Terminate The Program")
        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,"&Open" , "Open a window") # menu to open a window , this gives error


        menubar =wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        # binds event 
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Show()
        # Click on About Menu           
    def OnAbout(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A Small text editor","Simple Editor")
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        # Click on Exit Menu 
    def OnExit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)
        # Click on Open 
    def OnOpen(self, e):
        self.dirname = ''
        dlg =  wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose A file",self.dirname,"","*.*",wx.OPEN) # this line also gives error
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename),'r')
            self.control.SetValue(f.read())
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small Editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

No traceback is given, Python interpreter crashes:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x016688e3 in pythonw.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

**Can anybody give me a reason and the solution for this?**

Comment: `/* */` comments are not valid in Python (2.7 at least). It gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Please fix your code so we can run it.

Comment: Comments set aside your code works fine on `OS: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1`, `Python: 2.7.3`, `wxPython: 2.8.12.1`.

Comment: I am using Windows xp sp2. There it is giving error. Any idea?

Comment: Please paste your error traceback in your question.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x016688e3 in pythonw.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Uh, so the interpreter crashes big time. What is your Python and wxPython version?

Comment: import wxversion
>>> wxversion.getInstalled()
['3.0-msw', '3.0-msw']
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: means I have python 2.7 and wxpython 3.0

Comment: This issue is solved by changing wxpython version to 2.8.

Answer (score 2):

The correct constant to use is `wx.FD_OPEN` instead of `wx.OPEN`, the later may have worked in older wxPython versions. But even [documentation for version 2.8.9.2](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FileDialog-class.html) says `wx.FD_OPEN`.